# Weather data: hail data for europe (belgium)

Tags: data-request, weather

Does anyone know any website where I can get (in structured or unstructured form) data for hail events in Europe (especially Belgium)? I've found quite some (paying) sites for the US/Canada, but no site for Belgium. Ideally, I would need the size of the hail fallen and localization information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to search in different languages, so since you are interested in data for Belgium, maybe it is worthy to search also in French and Flemish/ Dutch and German.

- Search in French (événements de grêle), maybe you can find the following resources useful:

  - For Belgium : [meteo.be/fr/climat/evenements-remarquables-depuis-1901/grele](https://www.meteo.be/fr/climat/evenements-remarquables-depuis-1901/evenements-remarquables/evenements/grele)
  - For France : [infoclimat.fr/historic/](https://www.infoclimat.fr/historic/)
  - For Europe :

    - [Bilan de l'activite grele en france et en europe en 2018](https://www.catnat.net/donneesstats/dernieres-actualites/25597-bilan-de-l-activite-grele-en-france-et-en-europe-en-2018)
    - [Bases de donnees grele en france et europe](https://www.catnat.net/donneesstats/telechargements/bases-de-donnees-grele-france-et-europe)
- Search in German (Hagel Ereignisse)

  - For Europe : https://eswd.eu/cgi-bin/eswd.cgi

Comment: since I don't speak Flemish nor Dutch, I will  leave the honour of that search to you or to someone who does. Please feel free to edit and improve this answer if you find more relevant resources ;)

Comment: I already did this, and found most websites you showed, however they didn't contain enough specific data. However, the last one (german) search could do the trick! Thanks